# Functional login screen in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I am creating an App and need to have a login screen, when I put the correct login it goes to another screen.

I'm not getting very well with class references between python and kivy. For example, how to access kivy functions and classes in python and python in kivy

### main.py

```
class Root(ScreenManager):
    pass

class Login(Screen):
    def conf(self):
        if self.tex_usr.txt == self.txt_pass.text:
            self.inicio.lb_stats.text= 'ok' 
#By pressing the button that is in the kivy file, I would like to go to another one of it. the Call screen
class Chamada(Screen):
pass

class Prg(App):
    def build(self):
        return Root()
Prg().run()
```

### kv file

```
<Root>:
    Login:
    Inicio:
    Chamada:        
<Login>:
    name: 'login'
    GridLayout:
        cols:2
        TextInput:
            id:txt_usr
        Label:
            text:'Senha'
        TextInput:
            id:txt_pass
        Button:
            text: ' Entrar'
            on_release: app.root.current = 'inicio'

<Inicio>:
    name:'inicio'
    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        Button:
            text:'Chamada'
            on_release: app.root.current = 'chamada'
<Chamada>:
    name:'chamada'
    GridLayout:
        id:grid
```

I would like it to be compared if the user and password are correct, if yes, to the other screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference functions or variables in your `App` class, which you have named `Prg`. For example, create a function to test the username and password, then change screens.

```
class Prg(App):
    def build(self):
        return Root()

    def attempt_login(self, username, password):
        if username == 'Fernando' and password == '123abc':
            self.root.current = 'inicio'
```

Now you can call the `attempt_login` function in kv by referencing `app.attempt_login`, and you can pass the text from your `TextInputs` by referencing their `id`s (`txt_usr` and `txt_pass` as you have called them) and their `.text` value.

```
<Login>:
    name: 'login'
    GridLayout:
        cols:2
        TextInput:
            id:txt_usr
        Label:
            text:'Senha'
        TextInput:
            id:txt_pass
        Button:
            text: ' Entrar'
            on_release:
                app.attempt_login(txt_usr.text, txt_pass.text)
```

Comment: It worked perfectly, can you help me in just one more little thing? I would like to access the text property of Label stats if login is wrong, how to do this?

Comment: Great! You can give a Label an `id` as well, then just use the same `.text` trick to get the text of a label.

Comment: Yes, I put an ID on the label, stats.  but I can not reference it, I've tried self.stats.text, self.root.stats.text, self.root.current.login.stats.text.  but none worked, I have several problems to understand references between kivy and python rs.  would you have any books on that to indicate?

Comment: @FernandoFosterHomohabilis check out my youtube channels, I post kivy tutorials. To access a widget's `id`s in python, you need to call `your_widget.ids.some_id`. In your case, you would give your `Login` widget an `id` when you add it to <Root>, then in python write `self.root.ids.login_id.ids.label_id`